# Binding a 2D array into a Datagrid

Tags: arrays, vb.net

So my case is that I want to populate a 2d array from two fields in my database.
I've got a problem with assigning an array with a value which is a database field
and the second one is displaying the array in datagrid, i've coded dgv2.Datasource = myArray but it's still returning an error message.

This is my code:

```
Dim msql As String = "select item_id from detail"
    Dim arayT(,) As String

    CMD = New MySqlCommand(msql, conn.konek)

    Try
        Dim res= CMD.ExecuteReader()


        While res.Read()
            For i As Integer = 0 To x - 1
                For j = 0 To y - 1

                    arayT(i, j) = res.GetString("item_id")


                Next j
            Next i
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR")

    End Try
    dgv2.DataSource = arayT
```

So my question is 
first, how to assign record column from database as value into my 2d array? (i'm still not sure my coding is right)
second, how to view the 2d array into datagrid, i mean binding 2d array into datagrid

A few requests from me... please don't ask me to use a list of(t) or use LINQ cause I'm still not too familiar with them.

i have done some fix in my code but it didn't worked nicely..here is my latest screenshot
[image]

Comment: It is more common to use DataTable and TableAdapter if you are going to update the data later.

Comment: i'm going to compare this 2d array with another 1d array to create a new 2d array from it
so i need array to store the data temporarily

Comment: there's still no answer..did anyone knows the solution?

Comment: I assume that you can only bind to 1-d array. I am not sure you can bind to a 2-d array. Again,consider a datatable.

Comment: sorry i still don' get your explanation?
do you mean that i have to store my query into datatable and display it later into datagrid?

like i said on previous comment, i need the array for the comparing proccess, and as far as i know datatable couldn't do that.. so my choice is to use an array

actually i hope the answer like using a method in this link 
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1321050

it using a bindingsource method, but the explanation on that link is not too clear for a begineer like me..

Comment: my questions still got no answers..please someone help me to solve this problem

i think my question is the most basic of vb database programming

it,s just populating normal 2d array with sql query then displayin it to datagrid or listview or whatever

but all the search in google suggest me using LINQ, arraylist, list of but they all didn,t give me a decent explanation

for somebody who want to give me an answer, please not suggest me using arraylist, list of or LINQ
just a normal array(,) as string please

Comment: Check this out: [Binding a two dimensional array to a DataGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5806/Binding-a-two-dimensional-array-to-a-DataGrid).

Comment: @Neolisk, good link, thanks.

Comment: thanks neolisk, my problem is already solved..but i got a new one..
please visit this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813904/vb-net-error-populating-2d-array-with-database-field/20814759?noredirect=1#20814759

Comment: @SoniGunz: I'm glad to hear that. Please take your time to accept below answer or publish your own and accept it. This is to let other members know this problem is resolved, i.e. your are not looking for more answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi guys my questions is finally clear, this is the answer to my question

```
ReDim Preserve arayT(x, y)
For i = 0 To (x-1)
    For j = 0 To (y-1)
        hasil.Read()
        arayT(i, j) = hasil("kode_brg")
    Next j
 Next i
```

it turned out that i don't need to use while..

many thanks for Afnan, Neolisk and Emmad that had already helped me to answer my questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

What error message do you get when you set your 2 dimensional array as your datagridview's data source? Well, you can loop and assign the values to your datagridview if the data source command is giving you an error.

```
'Ensure that the required number of rows are available
If DataGridView.Rows.Count < some2darray.GetUpperBound(0) Then
 DataGridView.Rows.Add((some2darray.GetUpperBound(0) + 1) - DataGridView.Rows.Count)    
End If

'Also ensure that the required number of columns are available

'Fill up the datagridview with the data from the 2D array
For x = 0 to some2darray.GetUpperBound(0)
 For y = 0 to some2darray.GetUpperBound(1)
   DataGridView.Item(y, x).Value = some2darray(x, y)
 Next
Next
```

If your 2Darray does not have the point of the reference in it and it has to obtain its values from some other source then use this code `ReDim Preserve some2darray(x, y)` e.g.

```
For x = 0 to rowcountofthesource
 For y = 0 to columncountofthesource
  ReDim Preserve some2darray(x, y)
  'Code here
  DataGridView.Item(y, x).Value = some2darray(x, y)
 Next
Next
```

If your 2Darray is taking all of its data from another source in one go. Then ReDim Preserve your 2Darray to the total rows and columns of that source e.g. `ReDim Preserve some2darray(totalrowsofthesourcehere, totalcolumnsofthesourcehere)` and type it outside the loop as you don't need to do it again and again. If your array is empty before use and contains no data then you don't need to use `ReDim Preserve` , just use `ReDim some2darray(int, int)`

Comment: Did you try this? It does not run. You can't reference grid cells unless they exist. If the grid is not bound, they don't really exist.

Comment: It should work. I don't know about your array exactly so you can try swapping x and y in code in the for loops

Comment: you can refference them even if they don't exist, I've used this code in many applications that I've created

Comment: @afran, hi afran.. i've done like what you said,, but it seemed i still got an error somewhere..could you please correct my code?
i've upload a new ss of my error in my thread..

things to note: 
-the field i want to fetch into 2d array and display into grid is "kode_brg"

-x and y is the variable which contains lower and upper bound of my array

Comment: @SoniGunz I've updated my answer according to your requirement :) . and by the my name is Afnan not afran :D

Comment: @SoniGunz if x and y are the upper bounds of your array then you don't need to add - 1 in the end. Add - 1 if it is the count or length

Comment: my bad, my eyes were so sleepy back then that i'd mispelled your name..haha

Comment: i think my case is like the second
my array is empty before use, so i declare my aray like this outside the loop

    Dim arayT(,) As String
i'd already tried your suggestion to redim arayT(x,y) where x and y is the total rows and cols inside my loop..
but it only return "index out of bounds result"

i've update my error ss, can you take a look at it again, please?
i think my problem is grid doesn't recognize my array's element as an object..that's what i think as an primary issues

Comment: ok, try this OUTSIDE THE FOR LOOP , ReDim some2darray(x, y) as x and y are the bounds as you said. now after it use this code some2darray = hasil("kode_brg") . Type these codes outside the loop and inside the loop only assign values to the datagridview

Comment: @afnan: i've already succeced in bind the 2d array into grid.. but there's a new problem popped out.. the datareader only read my database field once then loop it inside nested for, resulting in my 2darray only has one kind of "kode_brg"..
you can take a look at my newly screenshot

Comment: @SoniGunz can you please confirm that your 2darray has all the values of hasil("kode_brg")? maybe that your 2darray itself has t1 on all its points?!? IF your 2darray has all the correct values then it means the datasource command is not working properly then use a for loop like I mentioned in my answer to plot the values in the datagridview :)

Comment: @SoniGunz please type ReDim arayT outside the for loops and you don't need to type Preserve because there is nothing to preserve before the loop. Type ReDim arayT(x, y) outside BOTH of the for loops and please answer to my previous comment :)

Comment: @AfnanMakhdoom : my 2darray is supposed to have all the value of "kode_brg". the query worked fine (as you can see on my latest ss). so the problem is the usage of while looping that causing datareader only fetch value of field "kode_brg" once, resulting in my 2d array only contains "t1"
which previous comment you mean? sorry i missed them.

Comment: @SoniGunz I'm glad that you found your solution bro, I didn't concenterate on the sql part so couldn't help you with the while loop. by the way bro, you don't need the "Preserve" statement :)