# VB.NET Error Populating 2d Array with database field

Tags: vb.net

i have a query that contains field "kode_brg"
i want to fill them into array2d, i'm using mysqldatareader to fill the field into array2d, but it seems that the datareader only read once inside the while looping
for more specific, i've added the ss of myproblem belom

i'm pretty sure that i've made a mistake in using the **nested for** inside the **while loop**

could somebody help me fix this problem
thanks before
regards, me
[image]

EDITED: ADDED A CODE TO A QUESTIONS

```
    'FILL X

    Dim nil_x As String = "SELECT max( kode_faktur ) FROM detail"
    Dim x As Int32
    Dim CMD_X = New MySqlCommand(nil_x, conn.konek)
    x = Convert.ToInt32(CMD_X.ExecuteScalar())

    'FILL Y

    Dim nil_y As String = "select max(x.jumlah) from (select count(*) as jumlah from      detail group by kode_faktur)x"
    Dim y As Int32
    CMD_Y = New MySqlCommand(nil_y, conn.konek)
    y = Convert.ToInt32(CMD_Y.ExecuteScalar())

    'LOOPING ARRAY TRANS


    Dim msql As String = "select kode_brg from detail group by kode_faktur"
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim arayT(,) As String

    CMD = New MySqlCommand(msql, conn.konek)

    'Try
    Dim hasil As MySqlDataReader
    hasil = CMD.ExecuteReader()

    While hasil.Read()

        For i = 0 To x
            ReDim Preserve arayT(x, y)
            For j = 0 To y

                arayT(i, j) = hasil("kode_brg")
                'Continue For
            Next j
            j += 1
            'Continue For
        Next i
        i += 1
        Exit While
    End While

    conn.konek.Close()

    dgv2.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.EnableResizing
    dgv2.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode =    DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders
    dgv2.RowHeadersVisible = False

    With Me.dgv2
        .DataSource = New Mommo.Data.ArrayDataView(arayT)
        .SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
        .AllowUserToAddRows = False
        .RowHeadersVisible = True
    End With
```

one big note from me
**DON'T SUGGEST ME TO USE ARRAYLIST/LIST OF/LINQ/DATASET/DATATABLE**
because what i really want to do is filling the 2d array with database field, comparing it with another 1d array, then create a new 2d array from both of them, finally i want to display the newly 2d array into the grid.. that's why i chose 2d array instead using dataset to fill my grid

i don't know how to compare list(of) or arraylist with 1d array, that's why i'm using 2d array (basic)
thanks you before :)

the desired output

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screen shots of code.  It's very hard to impossible (unless you have a huge monitor) to read.  Copy and past your code into your question.

Comment: You have an `Exit While` statement at the end of your `While` codeblock, so of course it's only going to read once.  `j += 1` and `i += 1` also make no sense, as these values will get reset everytime you enter the corresponding `For` loops (assuming of course that you don't exit the `While` after the first read, as you currently are.

Comment: hi, tim thanks for your correction and reply..
but if i dispose the exit while and increment of i and j
the program will turn not responding
so what should i do to fix my code?

Comment: @SoniGunz Have you tried to debug, what caused it not responding any error or sth?

Comment: i have tried to debug, then break it in the middle of debugging..
i found out that it happened to be an infinite loop..
later i noticed when i add an exit while, the infinite loop stopped, but resulting in only read my database field once.

Comment: I smells another possible problem in your query too. *"select kode_brg from detail group by kode_faktur"*, will return 1 `kode_brg` from each `kode_faktur` is that what you want? isn't 1 `kode_faktur` can have many `kode_brg`? -*btw, I think we speak same language. kode barang & kode faktur sounds familiar to me* :D -

Comment: @SoniGunz also try to run all the query you have directly in MySql just to make sure all returning expected result. Then debug in your program, is it returning the same data for `x` and `y`. Looking at the loop, I think it shouldn't be infinite, termination conditions are clear.

Comment: @har07: glad to know we speak the same language :D. i've tried to run the query and result return exactly like i want (see the database table on my posting). as you can see "kode_brg" starts from "t1", the next is "m2", "c5", so on. but the datareader only read once "t1" then looping inside nested for. so i think the while loop isn't working properly. if i don't break the while, it read my field continously, but without stopping.. e.g: after the while read the last "kode_brg", it will starts again from the beginning and cause infinite loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44081/discussion-between-har07-and-soni-gunz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you managed to get array size exactly the same as number of data returned from query, you can try to change the loop to following :

```
ReDim Preserve arayT(x, y)
For i = 0 To (x-1)
    For j = 0 To (y-1)
        hasil.Read()
        arayT(i, j) = hasil("kode_brg")
        'Continue For
    Next j
    'Continue For
Next i
```

Comment: 07: thx bro, it worked like a charm.. you're the best!haha B)

Comment: I'm relieved now. I felt down when I managed to help others but cant get fellas from my own country out of his problem.. *yang ini lebay* xD

Comment: hahaha, bsa aja bro. 
but well, lucky for me to encountered you (y)

Comment: bro, could you please take a look at my problem..
here's the link.
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/31312492?noredirect=1
the new problem is lookalike with the problem in this post..
thx for ur attention

Comment: bro could you take a look at my post here
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/31312492?noredirect=1)
thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea of what you're trying to accomplish, but this is how you should do it:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String(,))

While hasil.Read()

    Dim item(,) As String = New String((x - 1), (y - 1)) {}
    Dim value As String = hasil("kode_brg")

    For i As Integer = 0 To (x - 1)
        For j As Integer = 0 To (y - 1)
            item(i, j) = value
        Next
    Next

    list.Add(item)

End While
```

Comment: @SoniGunz If the while loop returns more than one item you do indeed need some sort of collection. In fact you'll need a collection of 2d arrays. Orelse you're stuck with one 2d array beeing overwritten each cycle. (As you have noticed)

Comment: +1 for `I have no idea of what you're trying to accomplish, but this is how you should do it`, it's like "I have no idea where you are going, but take the second streetlight on the left, drive 400 meters straight and your destination will be on the right".

Comment: @Neolisk Haha! True;) You could also say it's like "I have no idea where you are going, but i'll teach you how to drive"

Comment: @ neolisk and roger: haha, sorry for the blurry questions..
i need to populate the 2d array with database then display it to grid
the reason is because i want to compare my 2d array with another 1d array to create a new 2d array from them

then i want to display the newly 2d array into grid, that's why i take the complicated way instead of just directly using dataset or datatable to fill the grid

i don't want to use list of or arraylist because i don't know how to compare list of /arraylist with 1d array to create a new one from them

Comment: @SoniGunz: We appreciate your effort to explain what you are trying to accomplish, yet it's still somehow unclear to me. How about this - try to explain your **whole** problem in 10-15 words. We'll start from there.

Comment: @neolist: thanks for your reply, bro.
i want to create a 2d array, which the element is consist of field "kode_brg". (you can take a look at the latest picture i've attached). that's my current problem.
my whole problem is: create two arrays, compare them, create a new array as an result, display it in grid.