# Visual Basic - How do I create a grid using a 2d array?

Tags: visual-studio, basic

I am trying to create a seven by six grid. I need some help knowing how to do this so I can call to specific coordinates in the grid. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5806/Binding-a-two-dimensional-array-to-a-DataGrid

you can get this with a simple google search!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding a 2D array into a Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620867/binding-a-2d-array-into-a-datagrid)